# Applying CNN method for face recognition but get the value error

Tags: python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

*The proposed method can automatically detect the features of hyperspectral images under the condition determined by the algorithms, and achieve the correct and fast recognition results.*

Here I was trying to run the face recognition with using CNN method but then I got the error message as below ---

**

```
File "<ipython-input-6-fdb29ac830ce>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/MDIC/Desktop/Face Recognition With CNN.py', wdir='C:/Users/MDIC/Desktop')
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/MDIC/Desktop/Face Recognition With CNN.py", line 221, in <module>
    plt.plot(epochs, val_acc)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2811, in plot
    is not None else {}), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1810, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1611, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 393, in _grab_next_args
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 370, in _plot_args
    x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 231, in _xy_from_xy
    "have shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape))
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (2,) and (1,)
```

**

This is my coding ---

```
# Importing libraries
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import os

# Preparing dataset
# Setting names of the directies for both sets
base_dir = 'data'
seta ='Man_One'
setb ='Man_Two'

# Each of the sets has three sub directories train, validation and test
train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'train')
validation_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'validation')
test_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'test')

def prepare_data(base_dir, seta, setb):
# Take the directory names for the base directory and both the sets 
# Returns the paths for train, validation for each of the sets
    seta_train_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, seta)
    setb_train_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, setb)

    seta_valid_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, seta)
    setb_valid_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, setb)

    seta_train_fnames = os.listdir(seta_train_dir)
    setb_train_fnames = os.listdir(setb_train_dir)

    return seta_train_dir, setb_train_dir, seta_valid_dir, setb_valid_dir, seta_train_fnames, setb_train_fnames

seta_train_dir, setb_train_dir, seta_valid_dir, setb_valid_dir, seta_train_fnames, setb_train_fnames = prepare_data(base_dir, seta, setb)

seta_test_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, seta)
setb_test_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, setb)
test_fnames_seta = os.listdir(seta_test_dir)
test_fnames_setb = os.listdir(setb_test_dir)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator( 
          height_shift_range = 0.2,
          width_shift_range = 0.2,
          rotation_range = 40,
          shear_range = 0.2,
          zoom_range = 0.2,
          horizontal_flip = True,
          fill_mode = 'nearest')

img_path = os.path.join(seta_train_dir, seta_train_fnames[3])
img = load_img(img_path, target_size = (150, 150))
x = img_to_array(img)
x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)

i = 0
for batch in datagen.flow(x, batch_size = 1):
    plt.figure(i)
    imgplot = plt.imshow(array_to_img(batch[0]))
    i += 1
    if i % 5 == 0:
        break
        
# Convolutional Neural Network model
# Import TensorFlow libraries
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Model

img_input = layers.Input(shape = (150, 150, 3))        

# 2D Convolution layer with 64 filters of dimension 3x3 and ReLU activation algorithm
x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu')(img_input)
# 2D max pooling layer
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)

# 2D Convolution layer with 128 filters of dimension 3x3 and ReLU activation algorithm
x = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu')(x)
# 2D Max pooling layer
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)

# 2D Convolution layer with 256 filters of dimension 3x3 and ReLU activation algorithm
x = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu')(x)
# 2D Max pooling layer
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)

# 2D Convolution layer with 512 filters of dimension 3x3 and ReLU activation algorithm
x = layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu')(x)
# 2D Max pooling layer
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)

# 2D Convolution layer with 512 filters of dimension 3x3 and ReLU activation algorithm
x = layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu')(x)
# Flatten layer
x = layers.Flatten()(x)

# Fully connected layers and ReLU activation algorithm
x = layers.Dense(1024, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(1024, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(1000, activation = 'relu')(x)

# Dropout layers for optimisation
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)

# Fully connected layers and sigmoid activation algorithm
output = layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(img_input, output)

model.summary()

import tensorflow as tf
# Using binary_crossentropy as the loss function and
# Adam optimizer as the optimizing function when training
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.0005),
              metrics = ['acc'])
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator            

# All images will be rescaled by 1./255
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

# Flow training images in batches of 20 using train_datagen generator
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                  train_dir,
                  target_size = (150, 150),
                  batch_size = 20,
                  class_mode = 'binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                       validation_dir,
                       target_size = (150, 150),
                       batch_size = 20,
                       class_mode = 'binary')

# 4x4 grid
ncols = 5
nrows = 5

pic_index = 0

# Set up matpotlib fig and size it to fit 5x5 pics
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(ncols * 5, nrows * 5)

pic_index += 10
next_seta_pix = [os.path.join(seta_train_dir, fname)
                 for fname in seta_train_fnames[pic_index - 10:pic_index]]
next_setb_pix = [os.path.join(setb_train_dir, fname)
                 for fname in setb_train_fnames[pic_index - 10:pic_index]]

for i, img_path in enumerate(next_seta_pix + next_setb_pix):
# Set up subplot; subplot indices start at 1
    sp = plt.subplot(nrows, ncols, i + 1)
    sp.axis('Off')

    img = mpimg.imread(img_path)
    plt.imshow(img)
    
plt.show()

# Train the model
mymodel = model.fit_generator(
          train_generator,
          steps_per_epoch = 10,
          epochs = 80,
          validation_data = validation_generator,
          validation_steps = 7,
          verbose = 2)

import random
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img

successive_outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers[1:]]
visualization_model = Model(img_input, successive_outputs)

a_img_files = [os.path.join(seta_train_dir, f) for f in seta_train_fnames]
b_img_files = [os.path.join(setb_train_dir, f) for f in setb_train_fnames]
img_path = random.choice(a_img_files + b_img_files)

img = load_img(img_path, target_size = (150, 150))
x = img_to_array(img)
x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)

x /= 255

successive_feature_maps = visualization_model.predict(x)

layer_names = [layer.name for layer in model.layers]

for layer_name, feature_map in zip(layer_names, successive_feature_maps):
    if len(feature_map.shape) == 4:
# Just do this for the conv/maxpool layers
        n_features = feature_map.shape[-1]
# The feature map has shape(1, size, size, n_features)
        size = feature_map.shape[1]
# Will tile images in this matrix
        display_grid = np.zeros((size, size * n_features))
        for i in range(n_features):
# Postprocess the feature           
            x = feature_map[0, :, :, i]
            x -= x.mean()
            x *= 64
            x += 128
            x = np.clip(x, 0, 255).astype('float32')
# Will tile each filter into this big horizontal grid
            display_grid[:, i * size : (i + 1) * size] = x 
    
# Accuracy results for each training and validation epoch
acc = mymodel.history['acc']
val_acc = mymodel.history['val_acc']

# Loss results for each training and validation epoch
loss = mymodel.history['loss']
val_loss = mymodel.history['val_loss']

epochs = range(len(acc))

# Plot accuracy for each training and validation epoch
plt.plot(epochs, acc)
plt.plot(epochs, val_acc)
plt.title('Training and validation accuracy')
plt.legend(['train', 'val'], loc='center')
plt.figure()

# Plot loss for each training and validation epoch
plt.plot(epochs, loss)
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss)
plt.title('Training and validation loss')
plt.legend(['train', 'val'], loc='center')
plt.figure()

# Testing model on a random train image from set a

train_img = random.choice(seta_train_fnames)
train_image_path = os.path.join(seta_train_dir, train_img)
train_img = load_img(train_image_path, target_size = (150, 150))
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(train_img)
train_img = (np.expand_dims(train_img, 0))
train_img = tf.cast(train_img, tf.float32)
print(train_img.shape)

model.predict(train_img)

# Testing model on a random train image from set b

train_img = random.choice(setb_train_fnames)
train_image_path = os.path.join(setb_train_dir, train_img)
train_img = load_img(train_image_path, target_size = (150, 150))
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(train_img)
train_img = (np.expand_dims(train_img, 0))
train_img = tf.cast(train_img, tf.float32)
print(train_img.shape)

model.predict(train_img)

# Testing a random image from the test set a 

cal_mo = 0
cal_mt = 0
cal_unconclusive = 0
alist = []
for fname in test_fnames_seta:
    if fname.startswith('.'):
        continue
    file_path = os.path.join(seta_test_dir, fname)
    load_file = load_img(file_path, target_size = (150, 150))
    load_file = (np.expand_dims(load_file, 0))
    load_file = tf.cast(load_file, tf.float32)
    pred_img = model.predict(load_file)
    if(pred_img[0]<0.5):
        cal_mo+=1
    elif(pred_img[0]>0.5):
        cal_mt+=1
    else:
        print(pred_img[0], "\n")
        cal_unconclusive+=1
        alist.append(file_path)
print(alist)

print("Identified as: \n")
print("Man_One:", cal_mo)
print("Man_Two:", cal_mt)
print( "Inconclusive:", cal_unconclusive)
print( "Percentage:", (cal_mo/(cal_mo + cal_mt + cal_unconclusive)) * 100)
a =  (cal_mo/(cal_mo + cal_mt + cal_unconclusive)) * 100
   
# Testing a random image from the test set b

cal_mo = 0
cal_mt = 0
cal_unconclusive = 0
alist = []
for fname in test_fnames_setb:
    if fname.startswith('.'):
        continue
    file_path = os.path.join(setb_test_dir, fname)
    load_file = load_img(file_path, target_size = (150, 150))
    load_file = (np.expand_dims(load_file, 0))
    load_file = tf.cast(load_file, tf.float32)
    pred_img = model.predict(load_file)
    if(pred_img[0]<0.5):
        cal_mo+=1
    elif(pred_img[0]>0.5):
        cal_mt+=1
    else:
        print(pred_img[0], "\n")
        cal_unconclusive+=1
        alist.append(file_path)
print(alist)

print("Identified as: \n")
print("Man_One:", cal_mo)
print("Man_Two:", cal_mt)
print( "Inconclusive:", cal_unconclusive)
print( "Percentage:", (cal_mt/(cal_mo + cal_mt + cal_unconclusive)) * 100)
b =  (cal_mt/(cal_mo + cal_mt + cal_unconclusive)) * 100             

avg = (a+b)/2
print("Average Percentage:", avg)
```

Kindly look carefully at the above programming since it is a little bit long

Please help me a soon as possible

**Thank you very much**

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your validation generated data terminates before reaching the 80 epochs of training. Check that you have at least `7*80` validation images.

Then check the number of elements in your: `mymodel.history['val_acc']`. It must be the same for training and validation if you use the `epochs = range(len(acc))` as your x values for the graphs. The problem is that your `acc` and `val_acc` have different number of elements.

Comment: My data are as below ---
[
Training samples = 100 for Man_One and
Training samples = 100 for Man_Two
]
[Validation samples = 20 for Man_One and
Validation samples = 20 for Man_Two
]
[Test samples = 30 for Man_One and
Test samples = 30 for Man_Two ]

Not sure which part is not correct -------------

Comment: The programming is OK one year ago and not any problem and even put into my master degree thesis --- but today suddenly got this error

Comment: If I want to put the training samples = 100 and put the validation samples = 30 then how to write the correct programming code for the above --- please help ---

Comment: If you only have 200 samples for training and 40 for validation and you have a batch_size of 20 then you should set your steps_per_epoch parameter at a value <= 10 and set your  your validation_steps at a value <= 2. Try with 10 and 2 and see if it works

Comment: Can you please write the coding or the statement based on your idea so that it is good for understanding

Comment: Yes it can get the results by setting the validation_steps = 2 and thank you but then why cannot set the validation_steps = 4 or 6 or 8 ----------- Please tell me the main point

Comment: You can not set validaton_step to 4 because you do not have enough validation images to use. With a batch_size of 20, at each validation_step you pass to your model 20 images to evaluate, in two step you consumed 40 images and then you do not have other images to do further validation steps. This is the reason why you can't do more steps. If you want to do more steps, you can decrese the batch_size, however for the validation phase it is preferred to use all your validation images and if you show them in 2 steps or more it doesen't change the result. The other solution is to have more data

Comment: Now I understand the important point and thank you for your kindness and support